# JavaScript code completion in Eclipse Juno not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete

```
var P = P || {}; // create global container object if it does not exist
P.file = {
    name : null,
    type : null,
    size : null,
    data : null
};
```

When I type `P.` in Eclipse, I don't get `P.file` as auto completion suggestion. Is there anything wrong with this style of creating objects in JavaScript? Or at least wrong with respect to code completion in Eclipse?

**More info:** This is a Java EE project with JavaScript support enabled. For global functions such as `function doSomething() { ... }` code completion works when I type `doSo` and hit **Ctrl+Space**.

Comment: It doesn't work for objects across files. It would work for prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that escalated quickly... somehow I didn't notice this, but in the *Outline* view of a `.js` file one can see that Eclipse treats `P` as a `boolean`, therefore no code completion. As soon as I use `var P = {}` code completion works like a charm.